# How do I get and set Environment variables in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, environment-variables

How can I get Environnment variables and if something is missing, set the value?

Answer (score 349, accepted):

Use the [System.Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment) class.

The methods

```
var value = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(variable [, Target])
```

and

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(variable, value [, Target])
```

will do the job for you.

The optional parameter `Target` is an enum of type `EnvironmentVariableTarget` and it can be one of: `Machine`, `Process`, or `User`. If you omit it, the default target is the **current process.**

Comment: Also note the optional third parameter:

System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable (variable, value, **EnvironmentVariableTarget**)

Possible values are: *Machine*, *Process* and *User*

Comment: Does `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine` requires Administrator access?

Comment: Yes, it does. Trying to run it without will result in an obvious exception.

Answer (score 46):

***Get and Set***

**Get**

```
string getEnv = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("envVar");
```

**Set**

```
string setEnv = Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("envvar", varEnv);
```

Comment: Can I set Environment Variable not programmatically? Trough project properties for example

Answer (score 39):

I ran into this while working on a .NET console app to read the PATH environment variable, and found that using System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable will expand the environment variables automatically.

I didn't want that to happen...that means folders in the path such as '%SystemRoot%\system32' were being re-written as 'C:\Windows\system32'.  To get the un-expanded path, I had to use this:

```
string keyName = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\";
string existingPathFolderVariable = (string)Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyName).GetValue("PATH", "", RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames);
```

Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: +1 I had to use this solution because the other one answered by Patrick Desjardins required me to have admin privileges. I was able to read the value of the environment variable without having admin privileges with this solution!

Comment: @TonoNam Patrick’s answer works in my machine *without* admin privileges. Note that setting System environment variable does require admin privileges (of course).

Comment: what about getting the `PATH` variable of the *current user* instead of the _machine_, how to do that?

Answer (score 19):

This will work for an environment variable that is machine setting. For Users, just change to User instead.

```
String EnvironmentPath = System.Environment
                .GetEnvironmentVariable("Variable_Name", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Variable name", value, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
```

Comment: If you want your PATH variable to be permanent use `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If the purpose of reading environment variable is to override the values in the appsetting.json or any other config file, you can archive it through [EnvironmentVariablesExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.environmentvariablesextensions.addenvironmentvariables?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ABC_")

var config = builder.Build();
```

[image]

According to this example, Url for the environment is read from the appsettings.json. but when the `AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ABC_")` line is added to the ConfigurationBuilder the value appsettings.json will be override by in the environement varibale value.

Answer (score 2):

Environment variables can also be placed in an application's `app.config` or `web.config` file, by their name bounded with percentages (`%`), and then expanded in code.

- Note that when a value of an environment variable is changed (or a new one is set), Visual Studio should be closed and reopened.

For example, in `app.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="%DEV_SQL_SERVER_CONNECTION_STRING%" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And then in the code:

```
string connectionStringEnv = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myConnectionString"];
string connectionString = System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(connectionStringEnv);
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be able to update the environment variable by using the following

```
string EnvPath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine) ?? string.Empty;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EnvPath) && !EnvPath .EndsWith(";"))
    EnvPath = EnvPath + ';';
EnvPath = EnvPath + @"C:\Test";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", EnvPath , EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2019 -- Right Click on your project, select Properties > Settings, Add a new variable by giving it a name (like ConnectionString), type, and value.  Then in your code read it so:

```
var sConnectionStr = Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;
```

These variables will be stored in a config file (web.config or app.config) depending upon your type of project.  Here's an example of what it would look like:

```
  <applicationSettings>
    <Testing.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="ConnectionString" serializeAs="String">
        <value>data source=blah-blah;etc-etc</value>
      </setting>
    </Testing.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

Comment: This misses the advantage of using environment variable - this snippet "hardcodes" the connection string in the config file, instead of relying on an environment variable.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.