# Connection String to Program files for access database

Tags: c#, winforms, database-connection, connection-string

My windows form is using Access Database.
How can i map the connect string to the folder in Program Files
For example, my database will be in the following location once installed

C:\Program Files (x86)\Amrit\trial\Database

Is there any proper way to make this work?

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access

Comment: all you need is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909788/how-to-get-installation-path-of-an-application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500829/sql-express-connection-string-relative-to-application-location

Comment: No, that's not the proper way, you cannot write to the dbase when it is stored in that location.  It needs to go into AppData.  Or preferably be stored on a file share so it gets backed-up at least once a day.  Access dbases have a knack for getting corrupted easily.

Comment: Stay away from `Program Files (x86)` or not. This folder should not be used to store program data. In the latest OS like Win7 and Vista you will have many problems accessing this folder and its subfolders also if you are an administrator. Use a different folder like ProgramData or something where you have full read/write permissions

Answer (score -1):

You can:
1. Add the Connection String to the app.config
2. use ODBC Connection
3. Check it out: [All the connection strings types](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: Answers should be more then just links.