# How do I detect the what's the base folder for Google Drive?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'd just need to detect the installation folder from a C# application so that I can open it. I guess that information is stored in a config file or registry setting.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/909835/1806218)

Comment: I'm sorry but this has nothing to do with what I need.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question before, you mean something like [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12173077/1806218)?

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't return the proper path. On top of that, I don't want to add a dependency to SQLLite just to open the Google Drive config info.