# how to find ms word installation path using C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, ms-word, epplus

I am trying to get the installation path of ms word through my code so that I can put its icon in my excel sheet generated through my c# code.

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909788/how-to-get-installation-path-of-an-application) but no luck.

Here I am trying to get the icon using the whole word installation oath which I know in my device but I want to generalize it.

> worksheet.Shapes.AddOLEObject(Filename:
>   @"C:\Users\BJS\Desktop\POC\wordFile.docx", Height: 80, Width: 90,
>   DisplayAsIcon: true, IconFileName: @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE", IconIndex: 2, IconLabel: "WordFile",
>   Top: _rng.Top, Left: _rng.Left);

Generalize the path which will work for all users

Comment: Is your code running on the user machine? Because otherwise there isn't any reliable way to guess the path

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to embed that icon into your project and use as ressource?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can archieve that with the registryeditor.
Open the key `HKEY_Classes_Root\Word.Application\CLSID` and save the Key Value.
Search it in `HKEY_Classes_Root\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{your_value}\Localserver32` (that's works for x64 systems, for x32 if i remmember right the path is "System" and not "WOW6432Node").

For how to read a registrykey in c# you can follow [that SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675864/read-a-registry-key)

As @Slai Say, that Will work only if you are Talking of server word Path and not browser user path