# How to add the dll search path in the code?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to append some path after PATH env item in the c# code, how to do that?

Comment: Try this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185208/how-do-i-get-and-set-environment-variables-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` method. More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable.aspx).