# Load my WPF Window application using command prompt

Tags: c#, wpf, cmd

When we type "Notepad" in "Windows > Run" the Notepad is launched.

In the same way, I would like to load my WPF window Application when a user types the program name in "Windows > RUN" or in command prompt(cmd).

What should I do to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

The reason simply typing `notepad` works, and you are not required to type the full path of `C:\Windows\notepad` is because `C:\Windows\` is in the `PATH` environment variable.

Therefore, in order for Windows to be able to find your program when you type `myProgram`, and not require your users to type `C:\Program Files\myProgram\myProgram`, the program's location must be in the `PATH` environment variable.

To do this from code in an install program, see [How do I get and set Environment variables in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185208/how-do-i-get-and-set-environment-variables-in-c).

Comment: I want to add Environment variables when my application is installing. I am using Visual Studio 2010 Setup.

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread:

[Run Windows application from Command Prompt](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/3b844e35-7788-45b0-a040-c6887f78bb13/)

Regards