# Can I use environment variables in a .settings file?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, application-settings

.NET allows me to create and access values that are persistent between sessions.
Is it possible to use environment variables such as `%WINDIR%`, `%APPDATA%` and others?
If so, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you talking about [Environment Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653(v=vs.85).aspx) ? if so then see [How do I get and set Environment variables in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185208/how-do-i-get-and-set-environment-variables-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have this in the config:

```
 <appSettings>
   <add key="SomePath" value="%TEMP%"/>
 </appSettings>
```

Then from code you'd do something like:

```
string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomePath"];
string fullPath = System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);
```

Comment: So, this would change the path `%TEMP%/foobar` into `C:/Windows/Temp/foobar/`, right?

Comment: And the upvotes and marked answer go to..

Thanks, this will help me greatly.