# Windows variable in C#

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file

How to get windows environment variabe in the C# code.

1. I have a windows startup script to set the environment variables.
2. I need to pass this variable to C# code..something like %var%

e.g. in the C# file, replace `D:\` with `%var%`. The value of var is stored as an environment variable in windows.

Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185208/how-do-i-get-and-set-environment-variables-in-c

Comment: Indeed. Voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: It's a duplicate, but why the downvotes without a comment for the OP?

Comment: Aah, 3 down votes. LOL. Sorry, I am a Linux person, never worked on C#. Niether on Windows, so it could be a silly question for those who knows windows and C#. I have a small requirement to do this job.

Comment: @PaoloTedesco - probably because it's easily Googleable?

Comment: @ShwetaChandrakar If it helps you feel any better: currently you've got 5 downvotes and 3 upvotes. So there are people here, who think your question is worthwhile.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables dear little Robert Drop Table Students, what I meant is that it would have been polite of the downvoters to provide a little explanation about why this question was deemed unworthy. Easily googleable as it is, I've seen worse...

Answer (score 4):

Use the System.Environment class.

The method:

`System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()`

and

`System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()`

Answer (score 0):

```
myvalue =  System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(nameofthedesiredVar);
```

This is the command.