# print all System.Environment information using System.Reflection

Tags: c#, environment-variables, console-application, system.reflection

We have a little task to print in a console window all the variables of the `Environment` class using `reflection`, but how to do so I don't even have a clue. I am sorry if I've written anything wrong here, I'm new to `C#`.

Of course I could use this kind of code, but that is not what is required from me.

```
string machineName = System.Environment.MachineName;
Console.WriteLine(machineName);
```

I searched Google so much and this is what I found, but I don't think this is what I need. I don't even know what I need.

```
System.Reflection.Assembly info = typeof(System.Int32).Assembly;
System.Console.WriteLine(info);
```

Any suggestions, clues?

Comment: Look at the members in `typeof(Environment)`

Comment: Other than the [tag:environment-variables] tag, this question seems to be pretty clearly asking how to dynamically query all the _properties_ of the `Environment` class.  So why are two answers and a comment — not to mention the author themselves in accepting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23187385/150605) — mistaking this for a question about how to read environment variables?  If it was it should have been closed as a duplicate of something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/185208/150605).  "I don't even know what I need." seems to sum it up, so I'm voting to close, anyways.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You don't need reflection here

```
foreach(DictionaryEntry e in System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables())
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Key  + ":" + e.Value);
}

var compName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()["COMPUTERNAME"];
```

Comment: You should probably use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME")` rather than an indexer, otherwise this answer is fine. If you are going to access it with the indexer, at least cache the result of `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()`

Answer (score 4):

Get the all *public* and *static* properties of `Environment` using [`GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, then display the name and the value of each property:

```
var properties = typeof(Environment)
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

foreach(var prop in properties)
   Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(null));
```

Comment: Reflection is unnecessary here. Better rely on the public API `GetEnvironmentVariables`.

Answer (score -1):

Although it's an old question, there is a neater possible answer based on the accepted answer, using Linq:

```
IEnumerable<string> environmentVariables = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()
   .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
   .Select(de => $"{de.Key}={de.Value}");

Console.WriteLine("Environment Variables: " + string.Join(Environment.NewLine, environmentVariables));
```

Or, a shorter version of the same code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Environment Variables: " + string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()
       .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
       .Select(de => $"{de.Key}={de.Value}")));
```

Comment: This had long been possible when [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23187385/150605) was posted in 2014; LINQ was introduced with .NET 3.5 in 2007.  The key point, as the other answer clearly demonstrates, is to call `GetEnvironmentVariables()`, from which one can enumerate `DictionaryEntry` values.  I don't think this answers the question as-asked, anyways, which is about reading `Environment` _properties_, not environment _variables_.

Comment: I used the `GetEnvironmentVariables()` and iterated it using the `DictionaryEntry`, exactly like the accepted answer (which also didn't answer all the question). Regarding the Linq, that's a nice comment :)

Comment: "exactly like the accepted answer" — That's my point.  Why are two answers demonstrating the same core concept needed?  They're not.  And how does the other answer not "answer all the question"?  The only thing you've added here is `string.Join()`, which the other answer does fine without.  You're not printing anything to the console, though, which, technically, _is_ part of the question.

Comment: The answer has its own benefit due to its implementation, especially using the cast.  Regarding the console and the LINQ, I edited the answer to make it more accurate