# Issue calling a python script from an iron python script (which is called from c# script engine)

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, python-2.7, ironpython

I'm calling an iron python script from c# using

```
        ScriptRuntimeSetup setup = Python.CreateRuntimeSetup(null);
        ScriptRuntime runtime = new ScriptRuntime(setup);
        ScriptEngine engine = Python.GetEngine(runtime);

        ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("C:/KitGenerator/KitGenerator/LoadKitsFromDatabase.py");
        ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
        source.Execute(scope);
```

This works fine and using print outs i've proven that the code runs correctly.
However inside the iron python script is a call to another python script

```
os.system("ipython C:\KitGenerator\Kit-Generator\GenerateKitImages.py")
```

(i have tried it with just (ipython "GenerateKitImages.py")

THE ISSUE:
When i run the first iron python script using Ipy.exe both run perfectly fine and do as expected.
HOWEVER when i run the first iron python script using the c# script engine it only runs the first script and the second script is never called.

i'm lost on this one. I can confirm it is nothing to do with : permissions, dependencies.

a gold medal and pizza for the man who can fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, the `os.system` call should use a raw (r"") string:

```
os.system(r"ipython C:\KitGenerator\Kit-Generator\GenerateKitImages.py")
```

Otherwise the backslashes will cause issues.

However, since you said it works from ipy.exe, my guess is that `ipython` is on your [PATH](http://ss64.com/nt/path.html) in the first case and not the second case. You can set the PATH [environment variable from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185208/how-do-i-get-and-set-environment-variables-in-c), include the complete path to `ipython` in the `os.system` call, or ensure that the PATH is set before calling the C# program, by [changing it globally](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them).

Comment: Did you get your free pizza?