# Passing value from a C# program into a Windows environment variable

Tags: batch-file, c#-3.0, environment-variables

I have a C# program that calculates a date. I want to set an environment variable datayyyymmdd to be read outside the program to be expaned into a filename that I need to look for with the Dos code.

Can someone please help me with c# code sample or any link .

Thanks

Comment: Dos?! Did you manage to run .Net on Dos??! :-D

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get and set Environment variables in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185208/how-do-i-get-and-set-environment-variables-in-c)

Comment: I have a C# program that calculates a date. I want to set an environment variable datayyyymmdd to be read outside the program to be expaned into a filename that I need to look for with the Dos code.
 
To be more specific:
input arguements for abc are x and y.
I’d like to basically do like this… calling my program (say abc.exe")  that give date from batch file and in that batch file i wish to add something like this :
    Set var1=[call abc.exe.exe “E:\\flags\\reportVersions” “x” “y”
 
var1 should have the date that comes from abc.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your C# program so it just *display* in the screen the value of the variable instead of set the variable itself. Then, execute the .exe from the Batch file this way:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('abc.exe "any parameter"') do set datayyyymmdd=%%a
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.Do you mean that I just need to print my variable as console.writeline() and "for /F "delims=" %%a in ('abc.exe "any parameter"') do set datayyyymmdd=%%a" will give result by itself?

Comment: sir i tried but still,no result.Following is my sample code._:@echo off



for /F "delims=" %%a in (C:\Users\u316383\Documents\Backup\ConsoleApplication3.exe) do set datayyyymmdd=%%a.


ECHO datayyyymmdd.



 @wait 15:and simple code:using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program{
        static void   Main(string[] args)
                {
                  
                  Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
                 
                }
    }
}

Comment: You forgot the apostrophes in FOR /F command: `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('C:\Users\u316383\Documents\Backup\ConsoleApplication3.exe') do set datayyyymmdd=%%a`. The command to execute must be enclosed in apostrophes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Now everything is working without arguements but with arguement,it again giving no output:@echo off

FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a IN (`C:\Users\u316383\Documents\ReturnFileName.exe`) DO SET DATEVAR3000=%%a
ECHO DATEVAR3000 is %DATEVAR3000%

@Wait 15
 but how to pass arguement in this?

Comment: Just place between the apostrophes _the exact same line_ you use in the command-line to execute the program. For example: `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('echo one "some <special|chars>" more') do set var=%%a`

Comment: I Got it.complete code :@echo off
 
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a IN (`C:\Users\u316383\Documents\ReturnFileName.exe "C:\Users\u316383\Documents" "1232" "19901212"`) DO SET DATEVAR3000=%%a
ECHO DATEVAR3000 is %DATEVAR3000%
 
@Wait 15.Thanks all for help.

Comment: I appolozise for adding another problem.Now my code is working correctly but if exception comes in the program,DATEVAR3000 is only showing last few lines of exception and not all.Is there any limit of data that can be returned?/

Answer (score 1):

This is not a trivial task as each process has its own environment variables table, especially if the environment variable should not be set permanently for all running processes.

The solution is quite simple.

In your C# application create a batch file with the line:

```
set YourVar=datayyyymmdd
```

The C# application could create this batch file with name "SetYourVar.bat" in directory for temporary files. The path of the temporary files directory can be get within the C# application from environment variable **TEMP**.

Your batch file contains the lines:

```
@echo off
"Full\Name\Of\C#\ConsoleApplication.exe" "parameters for this application"
if exist "%TEMP%\SetYourVar.bat" (
   call "%TEMP%\SetYourVar.bat"
   del "%TEMP%\SetYourVar.bat" >nul
)
"Full\Name\Of\Other\DOS\Application.exe"
```

So instead of trying to set the environment variables to use in other applications directly within the C# console application, write the lines to set them into a batch file called next by the batch file which started the C# console application and next deletes this temporary batch file just used to set environment variables.