# How to read Environment variable set by Travis CI in C#

Tags: c#, mono, travis-ci

I've created an Unit Test project which requires a key which is not public, so locally I can read it from the App.config but then Travis CI doesn't have this key.

So I've added an Environment Variable in Travis CI like this:
[image: Travis CI Environment Variables]

When the Travis CI build starts it displays my variable in the log:

> Setting environment variables from repository settings
>   $ export TestKey=TestValue

But according to the log a simple test which reads the key fails with the error message `Key not set as environment variable`:

```
[Test]
public void TestTravisEnvVariable()
{
    string testKey= Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TestKey");

    Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(testKey, "Key not set as environment variable");
}
```

The [`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6(v=vs.110).aspx) method reads the variable of the current process.<strike>, but apparently the key can't be read in this case.</strike>

<strike>So how can I actually read this key?</strike>

**Update:**
It is not clear to me why it didn't work in the first place but the sample above just works the second time I ran the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this on Travis CI and `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TestKey");` works fine for me in a simple console app (specifying`EnvironmentVariableTarget.User` or `.Machine` in the overloads doesn't though).

Answer (score 1):

Your build and configuration is fine.

Seems like environment variables configured on the repository usually take some time to be available on builds (unlike .travis.yml env vars).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9845159/4399732)

```
string keyName = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\"; 
string existingPathFolderVariable = (string)Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyName).GetValue("Variable You Want To Get", "", RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames);
```

Try this

Comment: Travid CI doesn't add keys to the registry but to the environment variables.