# Asp.Net VNext App Settings on Azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service, configuration-files, environment, asp.net-core

I really enjoyed the new Configuration feature of Asp.Net vNext using de default appsettings.json

But I would like to change the values of that file when I publish the website as a Azure Web App.

The old web.config appsettings was easy to change and configure the properties on the environment.

Do you know how to do this?
I prefer to user the default provider instead of creating a custom configuration provider.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set App Settings in the Azure Portal, they become environment variables at runtime, and should get picked up by the ASP.NET vNext runtime. So you don't need to *physically* modify  your `appsettings.json` to achieve this.

Comment: Can you please post an example on how to fetch the environment data?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185208/how-do-i-get-and-set-environment-variables-in-c

Comment: I added env variables to the configbuilder `configurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables()` and then used `Configuration["APPSETTING_EnvVarName"]` for an environment variable that I saved at the Azure Web App's app settings in the portal.

Answer (score 1):

It worked very well David! Thank you!

Here a sample to help our friends with the same question:

startup.cs

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Set up configuration sources.
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
            builder.AddUserSecrets();
        }

        **builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();**
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();

        **services.AddInstance<IConfiguration>(Configuration);**
    }
```

HomeController.cs

```
IConfiguration _configuration;

    public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this._configuration = configuration;

    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {

        ViewBag.key = _configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"];
        return View();
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
```

}
@ViewBag.key

To see the difference, run the web app on localhost and on an azure web app changing the appsetting Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString

Best,