# setting Application Insights Instrumentation key in asp.net core RC2 on Azure web app

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I am developing a web application using asp.net core RC2. I am hosting this application on Azure WebApp. I am using application insights in the application. Now I would like that the Instrumentation key is read from the webapp App  Settings, so that my dev-ops can change it without redeploying the application(or I can add this to the azure web app without having to edit config files during automated deployment).

The only dynamic way I have seen is using

```
builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(instrumentationKey: iKey);
```

the problem with this is that the configuration is still not loaded so how can I read the value from web app to populate iKey.

Answer (score 0):

You can set instrumentation key through config. [See example here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/blob/master/test/MVCFramework45.FunctionalTests/appsettings.json#L3).
It will require application restart for new settings to be applied.

Comment: that is the question, I do not want the setting to be in the config, I want to read it from AzureWebApp settings. Like I have a connection string in my configuration which I can read locally and when my app is deployed on Azure I can read the connection string from Azure WebApp connection strings with exactly the same code.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732620/asp-net-vnext-app-settings-on-azure