# Getting environment variable in console app

Tags: c#, batch-file, environment-variables

I need analyze my environment variable value(COPYCMD)
Batch:

```
SET COPYCMD = /-y
SUPERCOPY.exe someFile.some someDirectory
```

SUPERCOPY - is my utility

SUPERCOPY code:

```
...
string environmentVar = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COPYCMD");
...
```

This string always returns null.
Also I have tried another way:

```
IDictionary environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();
if ((environment["COPYCMD"] as string).ToUpper() == "/-Y")
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

This way also doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure you have the element "COPYCMD" in your environmental variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get and set Environment variables in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185208/how-do-i-get-and-set-environment-variables-in-c)

Comment: In batch files the space to the left of the equals symbol becomes part of the variable name. Remove the space.

Comment: Yes, when i use this cycle:foreach (DictionaryEntry de in Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()) 
Console.WriteLine("  {0} = {1}", de.Key, de.Value); i see my COPYCMD

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that your environment variable has a trailing space in its name...

Try:

```
SET COPYCMD=/-y
```