# How do I make a dynamic url in c# to use for selenium testing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, url, dynamic

I currently have all the urls for my selenium tests hard coded using the local host.  When my application is hosted it will no longer be on local host.  For example in React, I am doing this:

```
`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/api/download`
```

Which fills in the first part of the url.  So if it is running on https://mywebsitename or https://localhost:44396 or https://localhost:5001 or something else the tests will still be able to pass.
Is there a way to do something similar in c#?

Comment: $"{process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/api/download"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185208/how-do-i-get-and-set-environment-variables-in-c