# Serilog won't log

Tags: c#, serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I have the following code:

```
var logFilePath = Path.Combine("\"%ProgramData%\\LogFiles\\Platform\\Tool\\\"", "config_tool.log");

// Default logging: Windows event log + console
var defaultLoggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.EventLog("Configuration Tool", manageEventSource: true)
    .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Information, outputTemplate: "{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
    .WriteTo.File(path: logFilePath, LogEventLevel.Information, encoding: Encoding.UTF8, outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zz} [{Level:u3}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}");

Log.Logger = defaultLoggerConfig.CreateLogger();

Log.Logger.Write(LogEventLevel.Information, $"{Constants.Common.AppName} ({AppVersion})");
```

There is no log file created. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `%ProgramData%` doesn't have any effect in C# like it does in Bash or File Explorer. Do you know how to lookup an environment variable value yourself? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185208/how-do-i-get-and-set-environment-variables-in-c

Comment: Also your first parameter to `Combine()` actually has *double quotes embedded inside of the string*. I'd be surprised if that would actually work. Double quotes around path strings are typically only **needed** when passing a path that might contain spaces as a parameter to a command in a Command Line Interface (CLI) window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get ProgramData folder and then create your path:

```
var commonpath = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
var logFilePath = Path.Combine(commonpath, "LogFiles\\Platform\\Tool\\config_tool.log");
```